# Appending and adding elements inside list which contains dictionaries as elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

There is a list which contains dictionaries as its elements. Each dictionary as multiple keys. I need to add values of other keys on the base of given key values. 
for example, There is a list A:

```
A =
[{'count': 100, 'price': [100, 200, 300], 'quality': 'good', 'key': 'veg'}, {'count': 150, 'price': [10, 20, 30], 'quality': 'good', 'key': 'non-veg'}, {'count': 200, 'price': [1, 2, 3], 'quality': 'good', 'key': 'veg'}, {'count': 100, 'price': [110, 220, 330], 'quality': 'good', 'key': 'non-veg'}]
```

I am trying to add the values of these elements on the base of 'key' value. I need the output like:

```
[{'count': 300, 'price': [100, 200, 300, 1, 2, 3], 'quality': 'good', 'key': 'veg'}, {'count': 250, 'price': [10, 20, 30, 110, 220, 330], 'quality': 'good', 'key': 'non-veg'}]
```

I tried using itertools functions groupby and map. But **NOT** able to get the result exactly as expected. is there any easy way of doing this?

Comment: `groupby` requires the groups to be contiguous, but your data alternate `veg` and `non-veg`, so you'll probably need to call `sorted` with the same `key` function before calling `groupby`. At which point is may be simpler and/or more efficient to just build up a dict as you go along, and then convert that to a list at the end. But really, unless you show us what you're attempting, and where it goes wrong, it's very hard to show you how to fix it.

Comment: what's the criteria to group items?

Comment: @abarnert yes, don't use `sort` + `groupby`. This calls for `defaultdict` instead

Comment: I mentioned the output format I am expecting.  The output I am generating is not even close to the expected output. The criteria to group the items is by the value of the key ( here "key", values are 'veg" and "non-veg"). All the unique values have to stay the same like "quality" : "good", "count" values are needed to be added and "price" needs to be appended.

Comment: How would you aggregate "good" and "poor" quality within "veg" group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I love [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), I don't think is a good idea here. Your elements alternate `veg` and `non-veg`, but `groupby` expects the groups to be contiguous, which means it's only going to work if you first call `sorted`, at which point you're throwing away all the simplicity and performance benefits of doing things iteratively.

Meanwhile, without sorting, it'll be a lot easier to build up a dict, keyed off the key values, than a list that you have to keep searching for each key. For example:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: dict(count=0, price=[], quality=''))
for entry in A:
    key = entry['key']
    target = d[key]
    target['count'] += entry['count']
    target['price'].extend(entry['price'])
    target['quality'] = 'something' # I don't know what your aggregation rule is
```

Now, `d` looks like this:

```
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {'non-veg': {'count': 250,
              'price': [10, 20, 30, 110, 220, 330]],
              'quality': 'something'},
             'veg': {'count': 300,
              'price': [100, 200, 300, 1, 2, 3]],
              'quality': 'something'}})
```

And if you really need the list at the end, that's easy:

```
[dict(key=key, **value) for key, value in d.items()]
```

Alternatively, if the dict structure turns out to be more useful than the list, just use that. (Use `dict.setdefault` instead of a `defaultdict`, or do `d = dict(d)` at the end, if you don't want `KeyError`s on later lookups to turn into default values, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

For a pure Python solution, `collections.defaultdict` is likely the best option.

If you are willing to use a 3rd party library, this is possible via Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframe from list of dictionaries
df = pd.DataFrame(A)

print(df)

   count      key            price quality
0    100      veg  [100, 200, 300]    good
1    150  non-veg     [10, 20, 30]    good
2    200      veg        [1, 2, 3]    good
3    100  non-veg  [110, 220, 330]    good

# define aggregation rules
agg_dict = {'price': lambda x: np.array(x.values.tolist()).sum(axis=0).tolist(),
            'count': np.sum,
            'quality': 'first'}

# apply aggregation rules
res = df.groupby('key').agg(agg_dict).reset_index()

print(res)

       key            price  count quality
0  non-veg  [120, 240, 360]    250    good
1      veg  [101, 202, 303]    300    good
```

Then to produce your dictionary result:

```
d = res.to_dict(orient='records')

print(d)

[{'key': 'non-veg', 'price': [120, 240, 360], 'count': 250, 'quality': 'good'},
 {'key': 'veg', 'price': [101, 202, 303], 'count': 300, 'quality': 'good'}]
```